# Is it possible to use javascript / jquery to disable link redirection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, scroll, hyperlink

I'm trying to create a one page website where the navigation elements are used to scroll to specific sections of the page:

http://disputebills.com

However, my issue with the "one page sites" is that anchor links won't get used as sitelinks on google. I tried the following by adding schema.org markup to see if that made a different, but it doesn't seem like google will register anchors for sitelinks in google search results.

**Example of navigation:**

```
             <nav role="navigation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
                <ul>
                    <li class="hidden active"><a class="page-scroll" href="#what" itemprop="url">What</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#works" itemprop="url">How It Works</a> </li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#who" itemprop="url">Who</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#why" itemprop="url">Why</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </nav>
```

**I want the above to show up as sitelinks like this:**

[image: site links in google]

---

---

**The javascript code I'm currently using to scroll to the sections on the page is this:**

```
//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I tried creating actual pages and changing the anchors to real links, but I'm not sure if it's possible to then disable those links to to keep the page scroll working.

So essentially the new navigation links would look like the following, but they would not actually direct to that page, they would just scroll to the section on the same page:

```
<a class="page-scroll" href="what" itemprop="url">What</a>
```

I know links can be disabled a few different ways, but using javascript(void); or other methods like that won't work because these have to be real links. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Here's an example:

http://codepen.io/candid/full/mJxZda/

Comment: `preventDefault` should do it

Comment: So would I move  `event.preventDefault();` above  `var $anchor = $(this);` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your code and prevent the event:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        event.preventDefault(); //This will do the magic
        $anchor.parent().addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + $anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Mindastic. Unfortuately it doesn't seem to work. http://codepen.io/candid/full/mJxZda/

Comment: Hmm may be i didn't understand your question, because i am checking the link you sent and it is scrolling OK without going to any other page.

Comment: Hey the first link "About" was the only one I changed. It' showing  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined. Try clicking the About link and you'll see it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You have a problem in your code. Let me edit my answer

Comment: Awesome! Scrolling works now. However, this broke the bootstrap scrollspy functionality that highlights the relevant navigation menu item. http://codepen.io/candid/full/mJxZda/... Any suggestion for that?

Comment: As far as i see in your codepen, the problem is that for some anchors you use "href='#name'" and for others "href='name'". My code in the answer assumes you don't use the hashtag in your hrefs, so all the hrefs should be "href='name'". Give it a try. I changed it in your codepen and i see the menu item in bold (i assume that is what you mean)

Comment: Wow thanks for all the responses. I changed to your suggestion: http://codepen.io/candid/pen/mJxZda. Here is what it's actually suppose to look like: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/. Notice the menu items get highlighted on scroll.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It works OK for me with that code.

Comment: Yea I updated the code. Unfortunately the menu highlighting doesn't change on scroll. Otherwise than that it seems to be working. I'm testing out with waypoints.js. Thought that might work to get the scroll position.

Comment: Why don't you do it exactly like in "http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/" but also add hidden links to the real page. That will make google index them. And, in your "#" links, add rel="nofollow" to prevent the bots following them. I don't know if it is the best approach, but may be it helps.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a slightly different architecture to your site?  Create the separate pages, keep your code as-is to have the one-page layout work to scroll to the in-page anchors, and include a site-map in a footer with links that go to the different pages.  This will maintain exactly what you are trying to do along with the one-page scrolling.  The Google links can then go to the actual pages which can then redirect to the main page by using the php

```
header('Location: xxx.php');
```

Comment: This is a great idea. I had actually thought about this previously but figured google wouldn't register 301's as sitelinks. However, watching [this Mat Cutts video](https://youtu.be/Filv4pP-1nw) makes it seem like this solution would work. Having actual seperate pages is probably better for seo purposes in the long haul, but this definitely seems like a viable solution if you don't want to actually create additional pages with content. So to scroll straight to those relevant sections could you add anchor tags to the page redirects? Example: `header('Location: http://www.example.com/#about');`